# How can i filter facebook leads from marketing api by creation_date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am testing this request in graph explorer and if the json object is not valid in "filtering" i will get according error. But when its correct like i assume i have below i get unknown error!? What am i mssing?

```
<Ad_ID>/leads?filtering[0]={field:'created_time',operator:'EQUAL', value:'2018-04-18 00:00:00'}&fields=ad_name,campaign_name,adset_name,created_time&limit=1000
```

ERROR:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "HJWkrFCRE1K"
  }
}
```

What i am trying to do is actually the following but unfortunatly the "time_range" portion of the url is completely ignored:

```
<Ad_ID>/leads?time_range={'since':2018-04-18,'until':2018-04-18}&fields=ad_name,campaign_name,adset_name,created_time&limit=1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see this question was posted already 3 years ago, but it still didn't get any right answer.

Since then the [Facebook Leads API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#filtering-leads) were improved a lot.

According to the mentioned docs, the correct filtering looks like this:

```
<FORM_ID>/leads?fields=created_time,field_data,form_id,id&filtering=[{"field":"time_created","operator":"GREATER_THAN","value":"1616731200"},{"field":"time_created","operator":"LESS_THAN","value":"1616817600"}]
```

Only LESS_THAN, GREATER_THAN, and GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL operators are supported.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you don't have an access token in your query